# Undefined offset:0 at HandleExceptions->handleError

Tags: ajax, controller, laravel-5.8

I have a page which is used to search the users. If I searched an existing user, the page will redirect to my wanted page. If the user is not existing, a message must be shown. But for me the message is not showing. I know may be this is a simple error, but it's not working for me. I am using Laravel 5.8.

Error is:

```
Undefined offset: 0
in ClientsController.php (line 344)
at HandleExceptions->handleError.
```

Here is my controller:

```
public function getMerchantDetails() {
    $user = $_GET['user'];
    $mid = $_GET['mid'];
    $activity = "User $user has searched this merchant";
    //This is for Activity Log Capturing. Added user variable
    DB::insert("INSERT INTO activitylog (mid,activity) values ('$mid','$activity')");
    //Activity ends here

    $mobile = $_GET['mobile'];
    $email = $_GET['email'];
    $m = '';
    if ($mobile != '') {
        $m = " AND primary_number = '" . $mobile . "' ";
    }
    $e = '';
    if ($email != '') {
        $e = " AND email = '" . $email . "' ";
    }
    $i = '';
    if ($mid != '') {
        $i = " AND mid = '" . $mid . "' ";
    }

    if ($m == '' && $e == '' && $i == '') {
        // print_r($m);
        // die();
        return response()->json(array('data' => ''), 200);
    } else {
        $res = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE 1=1 " . $m . $e . $i . " LIMIT 1"));

        if (!$res) {
            //$res_config = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT * FROM configuration WHERE code = 'PERL_SEARCH_MERCHANT'") );
            $perl_path = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT * FROM configuration WHERE code = 'PERL_PATH'"));
            $perl_output = exec($perl_path[0]->description . ' -merchant_id ' . $mid . ' -mobile ' . $mobile . ' -email ' . $email);
            $r = json_decode($perl_output, true);
            if ($r['status'] == 'success') {
                if ($r['id'] != '') {
                    $res = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id = " . $r['id']));
                } else {

                    $res[0]['id'] = '';
                }
            }
        }

        return response()->json(array('data' => $res[0]), 200); (line 344)
    }
}
```

My Ajax code:

```
 $.ajax({
        "url": '{!! route('clients.fetchMerchantDetails') !!}',
        async: true,
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            mobile: mobile,
            email: email,
            mid: mid,
            user:userid
        },
        success: function (response) {
            var data = response.data
             if(data.id!=''){

                clientEditUrl = clientEditUrl.replace(':id', data.id);
                window.location = clientEditUrl;
            }else{

               $('.searchOutputDiv').html('<h3>No merchant found!</h3>');
           }

       }

   });
```

Comment: The reason for the error message is you try to get the element of zero from null variable or not an array, so first try to debug the `$res` and check the data type.

Comment: Also, you need to follow the Laraver structure.
for example in insert statement you should be something like `\DB::table('activitylog')->insert([
'mid'=>$mid,'activity'=>$activity
]);`

and for access data from the request, you have to use it like this `$mid  = $request->get('mid');`. but also you should pass the $request in function like `public function getMerchantDetails(Request $request) `